# No puedo dejar el logo fijo en mi sidebar cuando scrolleo

Tags: html, css, responsive

Estoy haciendo una de mis primeras páginas web, y estoy teniendo un problema con el header. Trato de hacer algo como esto:

https://pallarols.com.ar/

Me gusta el menú lateral, y que al verse en móvil, el sitio se transforma en un header con el logo centrado y el menu se oculta, para ser activado con un botón.

Casi lo he hecho todo, pero tengo un pequeño problema con el header en la vista normal (no en móvil). Al hacer scroll down, el logo se va hacia arriba, pero yo quiero que quede fijo y solo moverse el contenido. Pero si pongo el header con `position: fixed` entonces el contenido queda debajo del header.

Este es mi código:

```css
html {
height: 100vh;
}

body {
height: 100vh;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0 0 20px;
  background-color: wheat;
}
.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 90vh;
  background-color: #222;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: transform 0.1s ease-in-out;
}
.content{
  margin-left: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  height: 100vh;
}

.menu-toggle {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  display: none;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {

  header {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
  }

  .content{
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  
  .sidebar {
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }

  .sidebar.active {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }

  .menu-toggle {
    display: block;
  }
```

```html
<body>
<header>
  <img src="images/logo.png" class="logo" />
</header>

<div class="sidebar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Mis Obras</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Talleres</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor...</p>
</div>

<div class="menu-toggle">&#9776;</div>

<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>
```

A continuación pongo unas capturas de pantalla para que se entienda mejor el problema (le he puesto colores de fondo a cada elemento temporalmente, para poder visualizarlo mejor):

[image: normal]

[image: scroll down]

Supongo que otra opción sería colocar el header dentro del sidebar, pero de esta manera no puedo hacer que se muestre como un header centrado en la vista móvil, ya que el sidebar se oculta.

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 1):

Tendrías que usar la propiedad `position: sticky;` para que el contenedor permanezca siempre arriba del todo cuando se hace scroll hacia abajo, e indicarle que tenga un `top: 0px;` para que no tenga ningún espacio encima del contenedor, de esta forma estará siempre posicionado arriba del todo de tu página. También modifiqué el `padding` para que el botón (de desplegar el menú) no se desborde de su contenedor (por el `top: 0px`):

```
header {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px !important;
  background-color: wheat;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
}
```

Código:

```css
/* añado esto para quitar los márgenes por defecto */
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  height: 100vh;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px !important;
  background-color: wheat;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
}
.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 90vh;
  background-color: #222;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: transform 0.1s ease-in-out;
}
.content{
  margin-left: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  height: 100vh;
}

.menu-toggle {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  display: none;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  header {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
  }

  .content{
    margin-left: 0;
  }

  .sidebar {
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }

  .sidebar.active {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }

  .menu-toggle {
    display: block;
  }
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/wBWzOZo.png" width="50" class="logo" />
</header>

<div class="sidebar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Mis Obras</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Talleres</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor...</p>
</div>

<div class="menu-toggle">&#9776;</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: @user8448402 recuerda verificar la respuesta dándole al ✔️ si te sirvió para que tu pregunta esté como respondida, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Bueno finalmente lo resolví reduciendo el ancho del header y dandole position:fixed en la vista normal y luego poniendolo al 100% y position:relative en modo responsive.

Así:

```
header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px 0 0 20px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {

  header {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fff
  }
}
```